# azure login with service principal using certificate from keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-service-principal

I am following the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-cli-latest
to create a service principal to be able to use in shell scripts.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalName --create-cert --cert CertName --keyvault VaultName
```

Using the above I stored the created certificate in a keyvault.

I could not figure out how to use the new sp however..

What I see from the doc. is :-

```
az login --service-principal --username APP_ID --tenant TENANT_ID --password /path/to/cert
```

But this is not working even though I downloaded the cert and private key from the keyvault.

How can I tell login to fetch the key from keyvault?

**Clarification (update):**

If there's really no way to use keyvault for service principal login, then I really wonder what is the point of two statements in that official doc. suggesting that way

1)

> The --keyvault argument can be added to use a certificate in Azure Key
>   Vault. In this case, the --cert value is the name of the certificate.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalName --cert CertName --keyvault VaultName
```

2)

> For certificates stored in Key Vault, retrieve the certificate's
>   private key with az keyvault secret show. In Key Vault, the name of
>   the certificate's secret is the same as the certificate name. If you
>   lose access to a certificate's private key, reset the service
>   principal credentials.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `az login -h`, you can see a sample of using a certificate:

```
az login --service-principal -u http://azure-cli-2016-08-05-14-31-15 -p ~/mycertfile.pem --tenant contoso.onmicrosoft.com
```

So you need:

- `-u` the id of the service principal
- `-p` the certificate file
- `--tenant` (or `-t`) the Azure AD tenant id

I don't think it can use a certificate in Key Vault to log in, as you need to be logged in to get a token to call Key Vault.
Bit of a chicken and egg problem :)

Comment: B.t.w. just noticed https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-cli/issues/1360

Probably that explains

Comment: I have provided a clarification on how to login with a certificate stored in Keyvault -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7489#issuecomment-1959439989